# Does a Python implementation of, or interface to, UCL exist?

Tags: python, algorithm, compression, swig, ctypes

UCL can be found here: 
http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/ucl/

I am wondering if there is a Python implementation of this library or, at minimum, a simple interface (via SWIG, or even ctypes) exists?

The only evidence I could find of such an implementation led me here:
https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?package=python-ucl-common&project=home%3Asjcundy%3AAccessGrid

Which when you try to download the package, you receive an error page.

Comment: `Disambiguation` The reference to the "UCL common..." at opensuse pertains to a completely unrelated project: This is some kind of defunct/superseded library of _networking_ and _multimedia_ -related software developed at `University College London` (UCL).  The UCL compression library is an open source project from `Oberhumer` an Austrian company which specializes in compression and cryptography software.

Comment: Their 'explanation' page sets off all sorts of snake-oil alarms for me, explaining nothing about the actual compression algorithm, but a lot about how awesome it is. http://www.oberhumer.com/products/nrv/

Comment: Nick, I agree. It's not my choice to use UCL - I am dealing with doing a little analysis on other's data manipulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many compression algorithms are available for Python, in `zlib`, `bz2`, `zipfile`, and externally, for example [lzo](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/) (on the same web site as UCL).

If you really need UCL, try [cTypesGen](http://code.google.com/p/ctypesgen/), which should automatically be able to provide you a Python interface to it.

Comment: Trying cTypesGen - I will update with any successes or follies. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this answer is a little late, but I've just done a simple implementation using cffi (https://bitbucket.org/cffi/cffi).

You can find it at https://github.com/jap/pyucl (only tested on Linux)

Comment: Very cool. It's never too late to improve my code! Thanks for sharing. If (when) I try it out, I will respond back.